# Making each test method run in its own instance of a test class with TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

So I thought the following code would run fine in TestNG, although it doesn't:

```
public class Tests {
    int i = 0;

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0, i);
        ++i;
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0, i);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make TestNG fire up a new Tests class for each test method?

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, because I want to run several different tests that have nothing to do with each other! I don't want to retain state between them!

Comment: Furthermore, if it retains state, how am I supposed to know which tests are running first and which are second or third?

Comment: If you want to run tests that have nothing to do with each other, why don't you put them in different classes?  If you want to ensure tests are run in order, you can do http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#preserve-order

Comment: If I want to test my Stack implementation, that'll need 20 unit-tests, are you expecting someone to create 20 test classes?

Comment: "If you want to run tests that have nothing to do with each other, why don't you put them in different classes?" The problem is precisely that they have A LOT to do with each other, and that's why I want them in the same test class and also that's the reason that having them cleaned up between tests is important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common solution is to use an @BeforeMethod method to setup test state,

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
   i = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Argh, isn't there something better?

Comment: not that I know of, this is the standard way to do it.  It usually isn't that bad, just move the initializations down to the @BeforeTest

Comment: I tried putting a setup method (I actually copy pasted the code you have shown) and it still makes the tests fail. It seems it's only being called once. It seems that "@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run. "

Comment: sorry, it is BeforeMethod, I'm used to junit's annotation, edited the answer

Comment: It works, Thanks. But I'll be using JUnit (which doesn't seem to have this problem). Adding @BeforeMethod to clean up state between simple tests (without singletons or IO accesses) practically redefines the concept of a half-assed solution.

Comment: @BeforeMethod (and @Before in JUnit) are the standard way to initialize state, not sure why you think it's a bad solution. TestNG makes it possible to reuse state from one method to the next (e.g. an expensive object) while making it easy to reset your state if that's what you want. In contrast, the only way to do this with JUnit is to use static fields, which should be avoided for many reasons.

Comment: @Cedric, I have absolutely no problem with the framework having means of achieving both ends: what bothers me is that it lacks a *genuine* way of achieving unit testing that resets state between tests. Having a @BeforeMethod is what could be considered a hack, at best. A sugestion, for instance, would be to add an @StatelessBetweenTests anontation to TestNG(although IMO state reuse should not be the default behaviour, but that's just my opinion).

Comment: In other words, in a *Unit Testing* framework, I'd favour solutions in which the default behavior is to discard state between tests(that is, *automatically*) while I do understand that for *System/Integration Testing* the opposite may be preferred. The question that remains is what is TestNG's primary target :)

Comment: devoured: Fair enough. TestNG aims to cover both unit and functional, and the current behavior is also more intuitive (ask around, most people don't know that JUnit creates a new instance before each method invocation). In my experience, JUnit's approach gets in your way more often than it helps (especially forcing you to use statics).

Comment: @Cedric: I wonder if using statics to persist state between *unit-tests* is not more of a smell than any other thing. I get your whole point about having expensive-to-create objects, but generally in a *unit-test*, you should be be testing small parts of the whole object, mocking the hard dependencies, so the tests run in a couple of seconds, at most. Here we're testing the logic, not how well a big object performs in a quasi-real world.

Comment: devoured: no argument there, you should probably not maintain state for unit tests. I was talking mostly about larger scale tests (functional, integration, end-to-end, etc...). I designed TestNG to cover both unit and functional, so it's usually a better match as soon as you need to do more than unit testing.

Comment: @CedricBeust 'BeforeMethod' solution might work for sequential tests, but how will this work on parallel test.  Lets say on above example there are two test methods which run in parallel. Instance variable 'i' will have unpredictable value...isn't it?  wondering if you have thought of any solution for this.

Comment: I agree with Abhijit. @CedricBeust what should we do if need state for parallel tests?

Answer (score 2):

By far the most common solution to this issue I have found is to use ThreadLocal’s and just deal with the fact that you only have one instance of each Test Class. This deals with all the questions on how to deal with parallel/threaded tests. This works, but is a bit ugly.

```
private ThreadLocal<Integer> i = new ThreadLocal<>();

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    i.set(0);
}

@Test
public void testA() {
    Integer i1 = i.get();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, i.get().intValue());
    i.set(i1 + 1);
}

@Test
public void testB() {
    Integer i1 = i.get();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, i.get().intValue());
    i.set(i1 + 1);
}
```

Now back to the root of your question, new instances for each method. 
I’ve been researching for a few weeks similar topics, and I have identified this is the number one issue I was personally having with TestNG. It has literally driven me crazy.

If I was to ignore the fact that your tests had a bunch of complexities, you could potentially hack together a work around to meet the requirements you listed.

A TestNG @Factory Factory allows you to create new instances of your test classes.

```
@Factory
public Object[] factory(){
    return new Object[]{new Tests(), new Tests()};
}
```

I’ve now created two `Tests` instances, to be ran by testNG

Then the issue is your tests still fail, because it will try to run all test methods on your test classes. In order to hack around this you could implement a IMethodInterceptor, and hack together a solution to enforce that each Tests instance only run one method. Maintain a list of methods, and go through them one at a time.

Here is a brute example I hacked together.

```
public class TestFactory implements IMethodInterceptor {
    private List<String> methodsToRun = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Object> testInstances = new ArrayList<>();

    @Factory
    public Object[] factory(){
        return new Object[]{new Tests(), new Tests()};
    }

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        ArrayList<IMethodInstance> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(IMethodInstance i: methods){
            if(testInstances.contains(i.getInstance())){
                continue;
            }
            String mName = i.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getName();
            if(!methodsToRun.contains(mName)){
                tempList.add(i);
                methodsToRun.add(mName);
                testInstances.add(i.getInstance());
            }
        }
        return tempList;
    }
}
```

Then add your listener to the top of your `Tests` class

```
@Listeners(TestFactory.class)
```

You can improve this by dynamically creating new instances of the tests in the factory. Also breaking the listener out into it's own file and numerous other improvements, but you get the gist.

Maybe a crazy solution like the above will work for you or someone else.