# Difference between TestNG @BeforeClass and test class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, annotations, testng

What is the difference between TestNG's `@BeforeClass` and the test class' constructor? How does it work internally?

Comment: Not sure how it works in TestNG (I use JUnit), but one obvious difference is that constructor is called for each created instance and @BeforeClass is called only once for all the instances.

Comment: @pkalinow Unlike JUnit, TestNG doesn't create a new instance for each test method. See [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842284/making-each-test-method-run-in-its-own-instance-of-a-test-class-with-testng).

Answer (score 4):

1. @BeforeClass methods are invoked after test class instantiation.
2. Exceptions in constructor will just abort TestNG test execution and no report will be created. Whereas exceptions in @BeforeClass will be displayed in resulting report and class test methods will be skipped (This behaviour can be tweaked using -configfailurepolicy TestNG parameter).

Comment: Are you sure about 1? I just tested it, and my @BeforeClass method was called before the constructor

Comment: Yes, I am sure. After your comment I run simple test and @BeforeClass was invoked after the constructor.

Comment: That is not how my environment behaves... Try running this code: https://gist.github.com/OskarD/c7427d463e5594729769ce96c6a66ada