# Issues while calling a method from another class in a program using testng with java

Tags: java, testng

I am new to testing with selenium and java. Was trying to automate the login function of a bank application:

In the process, I am facing a null pointer exception for one of the methods.

To start with, I have two classes:

1. open (this class includes the method to open the browser, log in with credentials and close the browser using `@BeforeMethod`, `@Test`, and `@AfterMethod`)
2. login (this includes the method which has credential details)

What I am trying to do is call the method from class login to class open under `@Test` annotation. Can someone help me with the error below

Class open:

```
package Jprogramming;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class open {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void link() {
        System.out.println("setting bank application");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Java_Work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://parabank.parasoft.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void credentials() {
        login la = new login(driver);
        la.username();
        la.password();
        la.login();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Class login:

```
package Jprogramming;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class login {
    WebDriver driver;

    By username = By.name("username");
    By password = By.name("password");
    By login = By.xpath("//*[@id='loginPanel']/form/div[3]/input");

    public login(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void username() {
        driver.findElement(username).sendKeys("abc");
    }

    public void password() {
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys("cba");
    }

    public void login() {
        driver.findElement(login).click();
    }
}
```

I am seeing below error:

```
 [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
 setting bank application
 Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 47261
 Only local connections are allowed.
 May 06, 2019 1:53:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
 INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
 FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod teardown
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Jprogramming.open.teardown(open.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

    FAILED: credentials
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Jprogramming.login.username(login.java:18)
        at Jprogramming.open.credentials(open.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


    ===============================================
        Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
        Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================


    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

Comment: While you can try my answer, I have a feeling something else is going on. Go ahead and try it, but if you can set some breakpoints and see if there is something interesting you find about when and how things are failing that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning WebDriver to a local variable inside `link()` rather than to the instance variable.

Change the line

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

for

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is incorrect and based on false assumptions. Leaving it here for context**

While I can't say for sure, I'm fairly certain `@BeforeMethod` runs in a separate instance of the class than `@test`.

So what can you do about it? Either of these options may work:

1. make the WebDriver `static` so that `driver` is shared across all instances.

   ```
   static WebDriver driver;
   ```
2. Use `@BeforeTest` instead of `@BeforeMethod`

I'm not as certain about the 2nd option, and that may not end up really being what you want once you get more tests if you want a new driver every time.

Comment: Although [this question and answer seems to suggest I'm lying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842284/making-each-test-method-run-in-its-own-instance-of-a-test-class-with-testng)

Comment: @BeforeMethod runs in the same instance of the class. In fact TestNG reuses the same instance for all tests inside a class, while JUnit instantiates a new class per each test method.